# Write a SQL function with that work based on the SQL Server version

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-function

We have clients that are running on SQL Server 2008 and 2012.

I want to write a function that is going to use `Format` function. I have a custom function that is doing almost same thing as `Format` in SQL Server 2008, but its performance is worse than `Format`.

I wanted to make it conditional so if it's running on SQL Server 2012, then it would use the built-in T-SQL `Format` and if it's on SQL Server 2008, then it use my own custom function.

So I wrote a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [system].[FunctionName1]
(
    @param1 VARCHAR(MAX),
    @param2 VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(Max)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQLVersion VARCHAR(16) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion'))

    SET @SQLVersion = LEFT(@SQLVersion, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', @SQLVersion, 1 + CHARINDEX('.', @SQLVersion)) - 1, - 1), 0))

    DECLARE @Return DECIMAL(4, 2) = CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(@SQLVersion) = 1
                THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(4, 2), @SQLVersion)
            ELSE 0
            END
    IF @Return > 11.0
    BEGIN 
        RETURN Format(@param1, @param2) 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN Format_Custom(@parm1, @param2)
    END

    RETURN NULL
END
```

The problem is in SQL Server 2008: the `format` function is unknown. So it throws a syntax error when I want to deploy it. I already have a work around for it with deployment script. But I want to know can I somehow with sql built-in functions pass the `Format` line or ignore it?

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be done in a function.

It has to be able to *compile* the code before any of your logic can execute, and it's failing at that point because there's a function it doesn't know of.

And you can't apply the usual work-around to get past the compilation error - putting the not-certain-to-compile code in as a string and compiling/executing it separately using an `EXEC` call - since you're not allowed dynamic SQL in UDFs.

Comment: could he not execute dynamic SQL dependent on the version? Then it wouldn't be compiled

Comment: @Alec - as I said, you can't do dynamic SQL within a function.